# Fill empty cell in a column if condition met in another column

Tags: excel, vba

In column "D" I have empty cells to be filled with the above value in the same column, if a condition in another column is met.

For each empty cell in column D, I am trying to copy the value of the cell above if the word in the cell of the same row in column E is equal to the word in the cell above in column E.
If the condition is not met then put N/A in the empty cell of column D.
[image]

This code seems to work but I wonder if there is a better way.
Also, I don't know how to write an error message or a "N/A" in the cell where the condition is not met.

```vb
Sub ...()

    Dim columnValues As Range
    Dim i As Long
    Dim columnref As Range
    
    Set columnValues = Range("D2:D2000")
    Set columnref = Range("E2:E2000")

    For i = 1 To columnValues.Rows.Count
        If columnValues.Cells(i, 1).Value = "" And _
          columnref.Cells(i, 1).Value = columnref.Cells(i - 1, 1).Value Then
            columnValues.Cells(i, 1).Value = columnValues.Cells(i - 1, 1).Value
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Posting the code you tried, along with the specific problem(s) you had with that code, is much more likely to get you help here.

Comment: Sorry about that, I edited my post and added the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand why you need VBA for this:

I just selected all cells in the column with the letters "aaa", "bbb", ..., I pressed <kbd>Ctrl+G</kbd>, and chose "Special", "Blanks".

Then I clicked in the formula bar and typed `=IF(E3=E4,D3,"N/A")` (my first "aaa" is located in "D3") and pressed <kbd>Ctrl+ENTER</kbd>, here are some screenshots:

[image: select column]

[image: select blanks]

[image: Blanks are selected, green arrow shows formula bar]

[image: Result after clicking CONTROL enter]

Have fun :-)

Comment: Thank you so much !!! I am so silly, I thouth I needed to use VBA but formulas work just fine too hahaha